# Software Updater wants to install two different versions of kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, update-manager

On **14.04.4**, Software Updater popped up and showed me this:

[image]

I am very new to Ubuntu, and this seems odd to see both vervet and unicorn kernel headers, kernel image, etc. So what is going on? Should I update only 3.19 and uncheck 3.16? Or does it matter? Should I remove 3.16 with `sudo apt-get remove`?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you install kernel meta-package manually by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

But you still have meta packages for kernel 3.16, that are `lts-utopic`.

You can remove all 3.16 kernels using Synaptic and meta packages will removed as well.

Alternatively you can remove only meta packages and leave the kernels installed.

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to removing meta-packages and leaving kernels installed vs. just removing kernels with meta-packages? Also what would be  the syntax to do it with `sudo apt-get remove` rather than Synaptic?

Comment: If you leave the kernels, you will be able to boot with these kernels. You can remove them using `apt-get` as well.